# I have Gradle error when i use firebase with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

Pleas can any one help me with this error i have it when try to run my app in Android Studio i use this dev

## Firebase And Notification

firebase_messaging: ^14.2.5
firebase_core: ^2.7.0
flutter_local_notifications: ^8.2.0
cloud_firestore: ^4.4.3

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
G:\Porjects\Flutter\commerce_app\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:cloud_firestore] G:\Porjects\Flutter\commerce_app\build\cloud_firestore\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:cloud_firestore] G:\Porjects\Flutter\commerce_app\build\cloud_firestore\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

┌─ Flutter Fix ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ The plugin cloud_firestore requires a higher Android SDK version.                             │
│ Fix this issue by adding the following to the file                                            │
│ G:\Porjects\Flutter\commerce_app\android\app\build.gradle:                                    │
│ android {                                                                                     │
│   defaultConfig {                                                                             │
│     minSdkVersion 21                                                                          │
│   }                                                                                           │
│ }                                                                                             │
│                                                                                               │
│ Note that your app won't be available to users running Android SDKs below 19.                 │
│ Alternatively, try to find a version of this plugin that supports these lower versions of the │
│ Android SDK.                                                                                  │
│ For more information, see:                                                                    │
│ https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration          │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried to change this line in android>app>build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.ahmedmaged.commerce_app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        **minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion   //this line**
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

to this line

```
**minSdkVersion 21   **
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your `minimunSdkVersion` hardcoded to 21

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.ahmedmaged.commerce_app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21 //flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

Comment: It gives me another error:

Comment: G:\Porjects\Flutter\commerce_app\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:15:9-22:20 Error:
 android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <receiver#com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

Comment: * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: What are the packages you are using? apart from this

Comment: # Firebase And Notification
  firebase_messaging: ^14.2.5
  firebase_core: ^2.7.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^8.2.0
  cloud_firestore: ^4.4.3

Comment: I you don't mind, can I get github link

Comment: sure:   https://github.com/ahmedbark129/commerce-app

Comment: Now, the issue is coming from `flutter_local_notifications` package

Comment: You may have to update that library, it will take longer time to migrate from that version. So for a quick fix, you have to add android:exported="false" for a tag ` <receiver>` in `AndroidManifest.xml` of the library manually(It is not a correct way).

Comment: the quick way doesn't work, I think the error comes from cloud_firestore

Comment: Yeah, both have `AndroidManifest.xml`. All receiver tag should have `android:exported="false"`

Comment: I tries but it doesn't work

Comment: What is the error you are getting now? Still same?

Comment: yes it is the same

Comment: Can you try upgrading your packages

Comment: i did but doesn't help